# C# Windows 10 OpenFileDialog with long path

Tags: c#, windows-10, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog, long-path

I have the same folder structure in both my C: and D: drive (both NTFS).
In regedit both LongPath and 8dot3NameCreation are enabled.

On C: Windows shortens the path as such: "C:...\LONGNA~1"
On D: it just puts the \?\ prefix before the path resulting in invalid characters according to OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog

Is there a way to use OpenFileDialog or FolderBrowserDialog to open a path that has the prefix \?\ signaling the use of long path?

fsutil queries return the following:

> fsutil 8dot3name query C
> Error:  The system cannot find the file specified.
> Trying to open the volume with volume GUID path.
> The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled).
> The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).
>
> Based on the above settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on C

> fsutil 8dot3name query D
> Error:  The system cannot find the file specified.
> Trying to open the volume with volume GUID path.
> The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled).
> The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).
>
> Based on the above settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on D

Comment: Try to use the SaveFileDialog instead of OpenFileDialog. SaveFileDialog supports long path

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10